# a ban on going to these places

Tags: meaning, quantifiers, any

a. You say there is a ban on going to some of the countries on this list. I think there's a ban on going to any of the countries on this list.

b. You say there is a ban on going to some of the countries on this list. I think there's a ban on going to all of the countries on this list.

I think (a) clearly states that the speaker believes none of the countries on the list can be visited.

(b) seems to be saying that the speaker thinks that one doesn't have the right to visit them all, but could visit any number of them provided one doesn't visit them all. (an absurd thing to say, but that is beside the point)

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Logically you are correct.

But most would assume that a ban on to going to "all countries" meant "any countries".